# Does the vaadin netbeans plugin have vaadin designer?

Tags: java, vaadin, netbeans-8

Am currently working on a GUI java project and am using vaadin plugin in netbeans. But I cant seem to find vaadin designer anywhere. I have search on the internet and can't really find anything related. So my problems is, is there a vaadin designer in the netbeans vaadin plugin. If there is, how do I implement it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Vaadin Designer is exclusively available inside the [Vaadin Eclipse Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vaadin-plugin-eclipse).

There is a working in progress attempt to port the designer on IntelliJ, but it is not yet released as far as I know.
Regarding Netbeans support, I think it is possible that will be implemented in the future, but no definitive plans are in place yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Later update**

Although not Netbeans related, I remembered about someone who created a designer project which may be of some help, so I quickly double-checked the Vaadin add-on collection and noticed it's still being maintained. If it can be of any use to you it's called [JaVaDe (Java Vaadin Designer)](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/javade) and it also has a [website](http://javade.businesscatalyst.com/index.html) with some tutorials and instructions.

---

Looking at the [Netbeans Vaadin plugin page](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans) , it seems that it only helps with a few development processes, without providing a GUI designer:

> Vaadin Plug-in for NetBeans provides help with developing Vaadin
>   projects:
>
> - Wizards for project generation
> - Preferences page for updating Vaadin version, setting widget set compilation parameters and more Vaadin
> - Add-on Directory integration and code completion
> - Code completion and various Vaadin related templates:
>
>   - Use client package for widget source code
>   - Generate client-server state object
>   - Generate client-server
>   - AccepCriterion DnD class
>   - Generate Connector implementation
>   - Create GWT module file More information about the plugin in the [Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/VaadinPlugin1.1.0)

Similar information is available on the [Vaadin site](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-netbeans.html#getting-started.netbeans)

> Without the plugin, you can most easily create a Vaadin project as a
>   Maven project using a Vaadin archetype. You can also create a Vaadin
>   project as a regular web application project, but it requires many
>   manual steps to install all the Vaadin libraries, create the UI class,
>   configure the servlet, create theme, and so on.

There's a [work in progress for a new NON FREE (as in payed) designer](https://vaadin.com/designer) built around the [*new* Vaadin declarative definition concept](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-declarative.html), which per my knowledge is available for Eclipse already, with the possibility to sign up for an [IntelliJ Idea early access preview](https://vaadin.com/designer/intellij), but I'm not aware of something similar for Netbeans so far.

**P.S.** The [old IntelliJ plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6727?pr) is no longer compatible with the newer versions of Idea, and I'm not sure whether the old Eclipse plugin (which had a decent GUI designer - see screenshot below) is still available and/or maintained. Probably it's been replaced by the new commercial version.

[image: old eclipse vaadin plugin]

Answer (score 1):

## Designer supported in IntelliJ & Eclipse, but *not* NetBeans

[Vaadin Designer](https://vaadin.com/designer) requires either [IntelliJ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) or [Eclipse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#). Not supported in [NetBeans](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) nor any other [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDE).

Per [*Release Notes*](https://vaadin.com/designer/release-notes) as of 2017-03.

## Vaadin Designer 2

Designer 2.0.0 is for Vaadin 8.

Requires:

- Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)+, Java EE edition. Eclipse Neon 4.6 recommended
- JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 14+ Community/Ultimate

## Vaadin Designer 1

Designer 1.2.1 is for Vaadin 7.

Requires:

- Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)+, Java EE edition
- JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 14+ Community/Ultimate